# Random combination of three to five words from the list in java

Tags: java, list, combinations

I have a String named `headline`, and it should be a random combination of three to five words from the following list: up, down, rise, fall, good, bad, success, failure, high, low.

I created a list such as:

```
List list= new ArrayList();
list.add("up");
list.add("down");
list.add("fail");
list.add("success");
list.add("good");
list.add("bad");
list.add("upper");
list.add("uber");
```

How would I get a random combination of three to five words from this list?

Comment: Call `Collections.shuffle` on it and take the last n elements

Comment: Is it an equal chance of being 3, 4, or 5 words? Do you care whether the same word appear twice in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use stream of random int indexes in the input list (then duplicate values are possible) with the help of [`Random::ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-):

```java
Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

List<String> combination = random
    .ints(3 + random.nextInt(3), 0, list.size()) // IntStream random indexes
    .mapToObj(list::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Example:

```
[success, uber, up, uber, fail]
```

Or distinct values may be selected with randomized `Stream::limit`:

```java
List<String> combination = random
    .ints(0, list.size()) // IntStream random indexes
    .distinct()
    .limit(3 + random.nextInt(3))
    .mapToObj(list::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Example:

```
[up, down, bad, fail]
```

Comment: now how to check  If more than 50% of words in the combination are positive ("up", "rise", "good"...) or not? @Alex Rudenko

Comment: Define a set of positive words, and count how many of the random combination is in this set:  `Set<String> positive = Set.of("up", "good", "success");  double percent = 100.0 * combination.stream().filter(positive::contains).count() / combination.size();`  Also, it may be better to use enum instead of plain String and provide `positive` as a field of this enum.

Comment: Thanks a lot It worked :) You are my hero . @Alex Rudenko